# Can Multiple Child Component gets a global input param in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component  with input param as name

```
 <lib-name [name]="name" > </lib-name>
```

These are called at multiple places in the project.

Now name is a app-constants which is assigned in app-component.

Currently i have to import name in every component ts file to pass it to library component.

Can we globally define this name for the child-component. So that my code will be clean

```
<lib-name > </lib-name>
```

Note:- Name can change on the basis of signed in user
Also it is a library component, i cannot just directly get the name in the library component.

Comment: You're better off implementing where you get the name as a service.

Comment: Still, i will have to pass it as input param, as lib component requires it as an Input

Comment: If a lib requires name as Input you have to provide it unless you can change lib.

Comment: @zainhassan I am asking if i can provide it globally without changing the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective {
    constructor(private lib: LibComponent) {
        this.lib.name = "Some Name";
    }
}
```

And use this directive

```
<lib-name appTest> </lib-name>
```

Comment: Thanks @zainhassan This helped me reduce the code duplicacy and additional imports for a same variable.